# Is there a way to change flags' tooltip font color?

Tags: highcharts

I tried to do `<span style='color:green;'>Test</span>`, but doesn't work. The flags tooltip text is always in black color. For line point tooltip, it's working fine.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You should set useHTML as true.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.useHTML

http://jsfiddle.net/VzrGT/

```
 tooltip: {
        useHTML:true,
        formatter: function() {
            return '<span style="color:green;">'+this.y+'</span>';
        }
    },
```